# Issues with migration EF Core + ASP Identity + IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, identityserver4

Trying to implement the IdentityServer 4 with Asp Core Identity and EF Core.
This tutorial to be precise (done every other before it as required): [AspIdentity with EF Core](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/8_entity_framework.html)

Everything is great until i have to run the migrations, which throws error:

```
An error occurred while calling method 'BuildWebHost' on class 'Program'. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Invalid object name 'Clients'.
No DbContext named 'ConfigurationDbContext' was found.
```

The full stack trace below:

```
C:\CodeRepos\horrorServerCORE\IdentityProvider>dotnet ef migrations add InitialIdentityServerConfigurationDbMigration -c ConfigurationDbContext -o Data/Migrations/IdentityServer/ConfigurationDb
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\horror\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[100403]
      Entity Framework Core 2.0.0-rtm-26452 initialized 'PersistedGrantDbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: MigrationsAssembly=IdentityProvider
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[200101]
      Executed DbCommand (7ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'__EFMigrationsHistory');
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[200101]
      Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'__EFMigrationsHistory');
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[200101]
      Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [MigrationId], [ProductVersion]
      FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory]
      ORDER BY [MigrationId];
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations[200405]
      No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date.
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[100403]
      Entity Framework Core 2.0.0-rtm-26452 initialized 'ConfigurationDbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: MigrationsAssembly=IdentityProvider
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[200101]
      Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'__EFMigrationsHistory');
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[200101]
      Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'__EFMigrationsHistory');
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[200101]
      Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [MigrationId], [ProductVersion]
      FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory]
      ORDER BY [MigrationId];
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations[200405]
      No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date.
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[200102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT CASE
          WHEN EXISTS (
              SELECT 1
              FROM [Clients] AS [c])
          THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
      END
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'Clients'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
ClientConnectionId:073e455e-7472-459d-9f9b-36504b8ef1ae
Error Number:208,State:1,Class:16
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[100100]
      An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query for context type 'IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.DbContexts.ConfigurationDbContext'.
      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'Clients'.
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, String method)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
         at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(Boolean buffer)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.GetResult[TResult](IEnumerable`1 valueBuffers, Boolean throwOnNullResult)
         at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext )
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.<CompileQueryCore>b__0(QueryContext qc)
      ClientConnectionId:073e455e-7472-459d-9f9b-36504b8ef1ae
      Error Number:208,State:1,Class:16
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'Clients'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(Boolean buffer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.GetResult[TResult](IEnumerable`1 valueBuffers, Boolean throwOnNullResult)
   at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.<CompileQueryCore>b__0(QueryContext qc)
ClientConnectionId:073e455e-7472-459d-9f9b-36504b8ef1ae
Error Number:208,State:1,Class:16
An error occurred while calling method 'BuildWebHost' on class 'Program'. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Invalid object name 'Clients'.
No DbContext named 'ConfigurationDbContext' was found.
```

My Startup.cs class:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            // Add application services.
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

            services.AddMvc();

            var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

            // configure identity server
            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
                // this adds the config data from DB (clients, resources)
                .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                            sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
                })
                // this adds the operational data from DB (codes, tokens, consents)
                .AddOperationalStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                            sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));

                    // this enables automatic token cleanup. this is optional.
                    options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
                    options.TokenCleanupInterval = 30;
                });

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                // this defines a CORS policy called "default"
                options.AddPolicy("default", policy =>
                {
                    policy.AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod();
                });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            InitializeDatabase(app);

            app.UseCors("default");

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseIdentityServer();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }


        private void InitializeDatabase(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
            {
                serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PersistedGrantDbContext>().Database.Migrate();

                var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ConfigurationDbContext>();
                context.Database.Migrate();

                if (!context.Clients.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var client in Config.GetClients())
                    {
                        context.Clients.Add(client.ToEntity());
                    }
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }

                if (!context.IdentityResources.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var resource in Config.GetIdentityResources())
                    {
                        context.IdentityResources.Add(resource.ToEntity());
                    }
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }

                if (!context.ApiResources.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var resource in Config.GetApiResources())
                    {
                        context.ApiResources.Add(resource.ToEntity());
                    }
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**NOTE: I started brand new project in ASP Core 2 framework so no migration from 1.x to 2.0 was needed.**

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You should post your Programm.cs too. Basically the DbContext discovery changed, see [my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45941707/why-remove-migration-run-my-app/45942026#45942026). Not sure this alone will fix the issue. I guess your Program.cs is wrong

Comment: I've not touched Program.cs at this stage. It is the default code that gets generated by visual studio asp core 2.0 scaffolding.

Comment: Do you have the IdentityServer4.EntityFramework NuGet package installed? That's the only logical reason I can think of that it wouldn't be able to find that context.

Comment: When you're running a migration you shouldn't also call InitialiseDatabase. Not sure if that is it, but I've seen that return errors that don't always make sense. 
Also, just for completeness, do post your Program.cs as there are some weird ways it needs to conform to be able to migrate contexts (it needs the static BuildWebHost method)

Comment: I will post Program.cs once i get back to desk. @janpieter_z that may just be it (re: initialise database), that is the only thing i haven't tried yet.

Comment: Hope it is that, let us know!

Comment: @janpieter_z bingo. After i commented out the initialisedatabase() it worked fine. Put answer up and i'll accept it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To run an Entity Framework migration you need to disable the `InitialiseDatabase` call.

Once the migration has been created you can enable it again.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's not your answer but if anyone else runs into this I found another cause. I was adding the ConfigurationDbContext to the DI container before adding it to IdentityServer and that caused the migration to not get added via IdentityServer.

Startup:

```
var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;
var optionsContextBuilder = new Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder>(options => options.UseSqlServer(authConnectionString, sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)));
// This caused my migration to not get run
services.AddDbContext<ConfigurationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(authConnectionString));
services.AddSingleton(sp => new ConfigurationStoreOptions { ConfigureDbContext = optionsContextBuilder });
// The above two lines needed to be moved below these lines
identityServerBuilder
    .AddSigningCredential(certificate)
    .AddConfigurationStore(options => options.ConfigureDbContext = optionsContextBuilder)
    .AddOperationalStore(options => options.ConfigureDbContext = optionsContextBuilder)
```

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: Thanks, man -- I don't know how you figured out this esoteric nonsense but you saved my day!

Comment: @Marcel ha dumb luck man, just trying different things. Glad it helped!