# EF Core remove applies not runned migrations

Tags: entity-framework-core

Im trying to remove a migration that went wrong. I have the following migrations:
InitialMigration
MyBadMigration

First my database state is at InitialMigration.

- I then run "dotnet ef migrations add MyBadMigration"
- I then run my application which updates the database with dbContext.Database.Migrate();
- My database is updated to the new state.
- I then realize that my migration is bad and I want to revert the changes.
- I apply "dotnet ef database update InitialMigration" and I can see that my database is reverted.
- I then want the snapshot and MyBadMigration.cs to be reverted so
- I apply "dotnet ef migrations remove"
- The database is then updated to MyBadMigration once more and I cant remove the migration.

If I use "dotnet ef migrations remove -f" when in InitialMigration the sourcefiles is updated (snapshot is reverted and MyBadMigration.cs is deleted) bu the database is still in the new state.

I use .net core 2.0 and ef core 2.0

Comment: Follow this guide carefully https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/
Especially updates to Program.Main method. dotnet ef builds your service provider to initialize your context but your code while building service provider is calling Migrate(), which is incorrect design.

Comment: This was the answer to my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45941707/why-remove-migration-run-my-app