# Calling a controller inside startup.cs of ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core

How can I call a controller method inside startup.cs of ASP.Net Core API? I want to build the cache on application start. Please help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You can not and you **shall not**. Requests require a connection and at the point in startup the application hasn't been fully configured/booted up yet. Also request require an instance of http context (which basically represents the request), which you can't do from `Startup`.

Basically it boils down to two options:

1. Create an powershell/batch/bash script which will call the endpoint, when the application is deployed or started.

   If you use IIS or Azure App Service to host your application, you can use [Custom Warm-up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-staged-publishing#custom-warm-up-before-swap) settings in `web.config`.

   ```
   <applicationInitialization>
       <add initializationPage="/" hostName="[app hostname]" />
       <add initializationPage="/Home/About" hostname="[app hostname]" />
   </applicationInitialization>
   ```
2. Option is to refactor your code and pull the things that require caching into a service, then resolve it during application startup and run it once. With ASP.NET Core this should be done in `Program.cs`'s `Main` method.

   See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45942026/455493) to see how you could set up warm-up during application startup. The post is about applying **migrations**, but same technique can be applied for cache warm-up.

   Do not run warm-up within `Startup.Configure` as it was common in ASP.NET Core 1.x, because tools like `dotnet ef ...` will execute it while discovering the `DbContext`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull out logic of a method of the controller in separate service and use it in case of start applications