# Error hosting asp.core 2.0 webapi in IIS

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have developed asp.net core 2.0 webapi and hosting in IIS. I installed the hosting bundle as mentioned in [Hosting Bundle Installation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis?tabs=aspnetcore2x)

But for some reason i am getting the following error:

```
An error occurred while starting the application.

.NET Core 4.6.25815.02 X64 v4.0.0.0    |   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting version 2.0.0-rtm-26452    |    Microsoft Windows 6.1.7601 S
```

Some of the error lines in stdout...

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.EphemeralXmlRepository[50]
      Using an in-memory repository. Keys will not be persisted to storage.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[59]
      Neither user profile nor HKLM registry available. Using an ephemeral key repository. Protected data will be unavailable when application exits.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.EphemeralXmlRepository[50]
      Using an in-memory repository. Keys will not be persisted to storage.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[59]
      Neither user profile nor HKLM registry available. Using an ephemeral key repository. Protected data will be unavailable when application exits.
warnwarn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
      No XML encryptor configured. Key {973e8bbf-2ca5-4c7f-a2ac-2672c9bb8041} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
      No XML encryptor configured. Key {973e8bbf-2ca5-4c7f-a2ac-2672c9bb8041} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\Elay\PublishOutput
Now listening on: http://localhost:30127
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[200004]
```

Any help?

Comment: Seems like an error in EF, Please check this http://vivekthangaswamy.blogspot.com/2017/08/microsoftentityframeworkcoredatabasecon.html

Comment: Also please check the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45941707/why-remove-migration-run-my-app/45942026#45942026

Comment: Thanks. i am using the database on the same machine where i have iis. so dont think it is connection issue.

Comment: Well, it *is* a connection issue, since that's the failure message you're getting. Perhaps the connection string is wrong/not set properly.

Comment: It is a connection issue.... That is the error message you are getting

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Will check the connection

Comment: @ChrisPratt, both are right. it is because of wrong connection. thanks

Comment: @Darkonekt you are right , it is due to wrong connection. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of settings you can add on to the WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder() method that will show detailed error messages instead of generic one when hosting .NET Core 2 apps in IIS.

```
.UseSetting("detailedErrors", "true")

.CaptureStartupErrors(true)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This was due to wrong connection details. It works fine with the correct credentials. thanks

Comment: Can you share what was wrong? We have the same issue but I swear it was working before we republished and now not.. the connection string looks OK

Comment: I would also be interested what needs to be changed in order to remove this warnings.