# .NET 6 how to run Migration automatically in program.cs

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

In .Net 5, we use to be able to call the migration by passing DataContext to Configure method and call the migration in startup class.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, DataContext dataContext)
{
    // migrate any database changes on startup (includes initial db creation)
    dataContext.Database.Migrate();

    ...
}
```

How can we do it in .Net 6?

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about, doing migrations and seeding in Startup have been deprecated since .NET Core 2.0 was released 2017. Simple search would have helped https://stackoverflow.com/a/45942026/455493. May be slightly outdated and methods changed slightly, the general idea is the same

Comment: What's the question? [Applying Migrations at Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=vs#apply-migrations-at-runtime) shows that `dbContext.Database.Migrate()` hasn't changed. Are you asking where to put the code that used to be inside `Startup.Configure`?

Comment: BTW thanks for helping me clarify the change from Startup.cs to minimal APIs in my mind. Up to now I've been writing the correct code mainly by checking which class has the properties I needed. That's the first time it actually clicked what goes where and why.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**Short Version**

It sounds like the real question is where to put code that used to live in `Startup.Configure`.

In `Program.cs` use

```
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<SomeDbContext>();
    db.Database.Migrate();
}
```

**Rather long explanation**

The [Applying Migrations at Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=vs#apply-migrations-at-runtime) section in the EF Core Migrations docs shows that nothing's changed as far as EF Core is concerned.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

    using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<SomeDbContext>();
        //Same as the question
        db.Database.Migrate();
    }

    host.Run();
}
```

It sounds like the real question is where to put code that used to live in `Startup.Configure`. That code can be placed in the `Main` method or, if Minimal APIs are used, inside `Program.cs`. `Configuration`, `Services`, `Environment` etc are available as properties in the [WebApplicationBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.webapplicationbuilder?view=aspnetcore-6.0) class or the [WebApplication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.webapplication?view=aspnetcore-6.0) created by it. `WebApplicationBuilder` contains the builder interfaces for DI, configuration, Logging and the host, eg `WebApplicationBuilder.Services` exposes `IServiceCollection`.

`WebApplication` properties expose the middleware configured by `WebApplicationBuilder`, eg `WebApplication.Services` exposes `IServiceProvider`

**Startup replacement in Minimal APIs**

The methods that were in `Startup.cs`were merged in `Program.cs` in .NET 6. Startup.cs contained two kinds of methods:

- Methods to configure the host and application, like setting up configuration and DI, by calling the various builder interfaces like `IServiceCollection`, `IConfigurationBuilder`. This includes the code that used to be in `Startup.ConfigureServices`.
- Methods that used the host to configure endpoints, use services and middleware. This includes code that was in `Startup.Configure`.

In .NET 6, the interfaces move to the WebApplicationBuilder and WebApplication classes. Instead of .NET Core calling a "magic" Startup class and injecting the interfaces, the code in `Program.cs` can access the interfaces it needs directly.

- The host building/configuration services are now available through the [WebApplicationBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.webapplicationbuilder?view=aspnetcore-6.0) class.
- Interfaces provided by the complete application host are now available through the [WebApplication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.webapplication?view=aspnetcore-6.0) class which is built by the WebApplicationBuilder.

If you *don't* need to configure services, you can create a minimal API application with just 3 lines :

```
var app = WebApplication.Create(args);

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.Run();
```

In your case you need to configure the DbContext at least, so you need to use `WebApplicationBuilder` and `WebApplication` separately. This is shown in the next section

**Migrations in Minimal APIs**

In the basic minimal API `Program.cs` :

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.Run();
```

DbContexts can be created once a `WebApplication` instance is created through its `Services` property:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
//Register the DbContexts etc.
...
builder.Services.AddDbContext<SomeDbContext>(....);

var app = builder.Build();

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<SomeDbContext>();
    db.Database.Migrate();
}

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.Run();
```

Of course it's a *lot* better to use separate methods or classes for such code, keeping `Program.cs` clean :

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddDbContext<SomeDbContext>(....);
var app = builder.Build();

ApplyMigrations(app);

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.Run();

static void ApplyMigrations(WebApplication app)
{
    using var scope = app.Services.CreateScope();
    var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<SomeDbContext>();
    db.Database.Migrate();
}
```

Or even :

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddDbContext<SomeDbContext>(....);
var app = builder.Build();

app.ApplyMigrations()
   .UseCustomLogging()
   .DoSomeOtherConfiguration()
   ...;

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.Run();
```

With `ApplyMigrations` an extension method in a separate class :

```
public static class DataExtensions
{
    public static WebApplication ApplyMigrations(this WebApplication app)
    {
        using var scope = app.Services.CreateScope()
        var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<SomeDbContext>();
        db.Database.Migrate();
        return app;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're the man!

Comment: But what about app services with multiple instances? Then the migration could be started multiple times causing surely an error!?

Comment: @HelloWorld no. the `ApplyMigrations` method is called by `Program.Main`, not the service constructors. Unless you mean that the DbContext was registered multiple times, which is a bug that would prevent the application from running?

Answer (score 11):

In ASP.NET Core 6, it should be:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("YourConnectionString")));
     
var app = builder.Build();
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<YourDbContext>();
    db.Database.Migrate();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this line `dbContext.Database.GetPendingMigrations().Any()` to check Pending Migrations

use it before `dbContext.Database.Migrate();`

**I use the following code and it works fine for me**

```cs
using (var scope = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().CreateScope())
{
    using(var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<YourDbContext>())
    {
        if (dbContext.Database.GetPendingMigrations().Any())
        {
            dbContext.Database.Migrate();
        }
    }
}
```