# Database AutoMigration in .NET 6

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, entity-framework-migrations

I'm rewriting a simple application that uses Asp.NET 5. but now I'm using Asp.NET 6 for the new version of my app. Quick question: what's the replacement of database auto migration (like below in .NET5) in .NET6 or What approach should I use for automatic migration after application launch in .NET6?

Sample in .NET5:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, PgSqlDbContext context)
    {
        context.Database.Migrate();
        /*
         other middlewares
        */
    }
```

.NET6 :

```
var app = builder.Build();
// ???? for auto migration
// other middlewares
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.NET 6 how to run Migration automatically in program.cs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70266442/net-6-how-to-run-migration-automatically-in-program-cs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried to add this code and the project works successfully.

```
var app = builder.Build();

using (var serviceScope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
   var services = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;
    
   var dbcontext = services.GetRequiredService<PgSqlDbContext>();
   var conn = dbcontext.Database.GetConnectionString();
}
//other middlewares
```

Comment: If my answer help you resolve your issue, could you please accept as answer? Refer to:[How to accept as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my translation from [Microsoft's Docs on 5 to 6 migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60-samples?view=aspnetcore-6.0#access-additional-services) to your use case:

```
var app = builder.Build();
var context = app.Services.GetRequiredService<PgSqlDbContext>();
context.Database.Migrate();
```

I did not test this, so fingers crossed!

Comment: thanks, but it did not work, cause the DI-Container can not find an instance of DbContext, Why? IDK. anyway, I handled it somewhere else in my application, but if you came up with any probable solution let me know.

Comment: @happykratos I'm assuming you are registering it like `builder.Services.AddDbContext<PgSqlDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("PgSqlDbContext")));` before `builder.Build()`?

Comment: yup, that's what I used