# How to fix error - Cannot access a disposed object in ASP.NET Core when injecting DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, ef-core-2.1

I have `ASP.Net Core 2.1` application & using `EF Core 2.1` as DAL

This is my how DAL service method looks.

```
public async Task<bool> UpdateChannels(IEnumerable<Channels> subscriptions)
{
    try
    {
        //here Context(MyReosiptory =DbContext) no issue
        var zoneChannels = await Context.Channnels.Where(x => x.isActive == true).ToListAsync();
        await Context.Channels.AddRangeAsync(subscriptions);
        //but at this line it throws the error.
        await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return true;
    }   
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message ?? ex.InnerException.Message);
    }
}
```

However, if I move the other Db Operation (add) in separate method, it runs.

But I have one more Db operation in the same method, & cannot move each Db related operation to separate method.

```
services.AddScoped<IMyRepository, MyRepository>();
```

Injecting the Dependency via Constructor.

Checked the below link.

[Cannot access a disposed object in ASP.NET Core when injecting DbContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38704025/cannot-access-a-disposed-object-in-asp-net-core-when-injecting-dbcontext)

But neither the Seed() is coming up nor do I understand why I should have Seed() & how it is related to disposed object.

Comment: I had the same issue but I do not remember if I did something else beside I added to  db connection string the option `MultipleActiveResultSets=true`

Comment: is your catch block outside the method?

Comment: @Fabio, I have mentioned in comments in snippet

Comment: How you are registering DbContext in DI services?

Comment: I expect you might be missing a call to `await` somewhere? e.g. Are you `await`ing the call to `UpdateChannels`?

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that includes all exception details including stack traces of the exception and all inner exceptions. Your current post is not an MCVE and it is hard (if not impossible) for anyone to answer your question.

Comment: Where is `Context` coming from? Is that instance of data context being passed around between objects at all? Does anything else use the same instance? We need to see more layers of this code to be able to help