# accessing dbcontext inside Startup.Configure while adding redirects using app.UseRewriter().Add()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, url-rewriting, entity-framework-core

I need to add redirects based on hostname, reading the map of source-path/destination-path from the database.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IMemoryCache memoryCache, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, myDbContext db)
{
    app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
       .AddRedirect("(.*)/$", "$1")
       .Add(ctx => {

            var req = ctx.HttpContext.Request;
            var hostName = req.Host;

            /*
            ** here I am willing to use db to do something like...
            */

            var redirects = db.redirect
                .Where(r=> r.host == hostName ).ToList();

            /*
            ** so that I can do something like this:
            */

            var newUrl = DetermineNewUrl(req,redirects);
            var response = ctx.HttpContext.Response;
            response.Headers[Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.HeaderNames.Location] = newUrl;
            response.StatusCode = 301;
            ctx.Result = RuleResult.EndResponse;
    }));
}
```

But it doesn't work, because db is supposedly disposed:

[image]

DbContext is added in ConfigureServices like this (scoped):

```
  var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
  services.AddDbContext<gommeautoContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection, sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
  {
    sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(maxRetryCount: 5,
    maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
    errorNumbersToAdd: null);
  }));
```

And my last attempt to make it work was using the following code:

```
  using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
  {
    var services = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;
    var _db = services.GetService<gommeautoContext>();
    var redirects = db.redirect
        .Where(r=> r.host == hostName ).ToList();
  }
```

But didn't help.

I assume it's not that simple to access `dbContext` inside `UseRewriter.Add(`, and I can't figure out how to do it...

Anyone does?

Comment: Scoped I guess, edited question to add a code snippet of how is added in ConfigureServices, my last attempt was this:            using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
            {
              var services = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;
              var _db = services.GetService<gommeautoContext>();
            } but didn't work.

Comment: Add that to your post, it will make things more clear.

Comment: Check it now. Hope is ok.

Comment: Looks good, take a look at this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38704025/cannot-access-a-disposed-object-in-asp-net-core-when-injecting-dbcontext) The accepted answer and the answer by Peter may help you. +1 from me.

Comment: @RyanWilson thanks a lot, Peter answer solved it!

Comment: you're welcome. happy coding. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach was actually correct:

```
using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
{
  var services = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;
  var _db = services.GetService<gommeautoContext>();

  ...

}
```

But I was misleaded by another issue, as pointed out here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43876571/395773 I had an earlier awaited call in my code returning void, implicitly disposing the context.