# Database SetInitializer is not found in MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using [MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore) provider to connect mysql.
Now I want to seed data while intializing database using `DropCreateDatabaseAlways`, But it is not found when I tried to use it like this

`Database.SetInitializer<SmContext>(new SMDbInitializer<SmContext>());`

and my `SMDbInitializer` will look like this.

```
private class SMDbInitializer<T> : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<SmContext> 
{

      protected override void Seed(SmContext context) 
      {

         //Some code
         base.Seed(context);
      }
}
```

Comment: EF Core != EF 6. Entity Framework core is a complete rewrite an more advanced verison of Entity Framework. `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` is a class of EF, not EF Core. For EF Core seeding patterns, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38704828/455493)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `DbInitializer.cs`  and call [dbContext.Database.EnsureDeleted()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.databasefacade?view=efcore-3.0#Methods); to delete the existing database .

```
public static class DbInitializer
{
    public static void Initialize(MyDbContext context)
    {
        //Ensures that the database for the context does not exist. If it does not exist, no action is taken. 
        //If it does exist then the database is deleted.
        //Warning: The entire database is deleted an no effort is made to remove just the database objects that are used by the model for this context.
        context.Database.EnsureDeleted();

        //create the database
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();

        // Look for any students.
        if (context.Students.Any())
        {
            return;   // DB has been seeded
        }

        var students = new Student[]
        {
        new Student{FirstMidName="Carson",LastName="Alexander",EnrollmentDate=DateTime.Parse("2005-09-01")},
        new Student{FirstMidName="Meredith",LastName="Alonso",EnrollmentDate=DateTime.Parse("2002-09-01")},
        new Student{FirstMidName="Arturo",LastName="Anand",EnrollmentDate=DateTime.Parse("2003-09-01")},
        new Student{FirstMidName="Gytis",LastName="Barzdukas",EnrollmentDate=DateTime.Parse("2002-09-01")},

        };
        foreach (Student s in students)
        {
            context.Students.Add(s);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();

        //Applies any pending migrations for the context to the database.Will create the database if it does not already exist.
        //Note that this API is mutually exclusive with DbContext.Database.EnsureCreated().
        //EnsureCreated does not use migrations to create the database and therefore the
        //database that is created cannot be later updated using migrations.
        context.Database.Migrate();
    }
}
```

In Program.cs, modify the Main method to do the following on application startup:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();

  using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
 {
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
    try
    {
        var context = services.GetRequiredService<SchoolContext>();
        DbInitializer.Initialize(context);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
        logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while seeding the database.");
    }
}

 host.Run();
}
```