# .Net core DBContext disposes after Task.Delay

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, repository, dbcontext

Net core repository pattern. I have below piece of code

```
   public class MapFileUploadBusinessLogic : IMapFileUploadBusinessLogic
     {
      public MapFileUploadBusinessLogic(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory, IOptions<AuthenticationConfig> authenticationConfig, IOptions<ADFClient> AdfClient, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IConfiguration configuration, IMapper mapper, ILogger<MapFileUploadBusinessLogic> logger)
        {
            UnitOfWork = unitOfWork ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(unitOfWork));
            Configuration = configuration ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configuration));
            CoordinateReferenceSystemRepository = UnitOfWork.GetRepository<CoordinateReferenceSystem>();
            this.Logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
            MapUploadRepository = UnitOfWork.GetRepository<MapUpload>();
            azureDataFactoryRepository = unitOfWork.GetAzureRepository();
            this._authenticationConfig = authenticationConfig.Value;
            this._ADFClient = AdfClient.Value;
            this.scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
        }
 public AuthenticationConfig _authenticationConfig { get; set; }

 public ADFClient _ADFClient { get; set; }
 public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
 private IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; }
 private IDbRepository<MapUpload> MapUploadRepository { get; set; }

 public async Task UploadMapFile(List<MapFileUploadEntity> mapFileUploadEntities)
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                {"Parameters", mapFileUploadEntities }
            };
            DataFactoryManagementClient dataFactoryManagementClient = azureDataFactoryRepository.InitiateConnection(_authenticationConfig);

            var result = await azureDataFactoryRepository.RunADFPipeline(dataFactoryManagementClient, parameters, _ADFClient, ApplicationConstants.SciHubPipeline);

            await Task.Delay(15000);

            ADFPipeLineStatus aDFPipeLineStatus = await azureDataFactoryRepository.GetPipelineInfoAsync(dataFactoryManagementClient, _ADFClient, result);
            if(aDFPipeLineStatus.Status == "Succeeded")
            {
               var mapUploadData = await this.MapUploadRepository.GetAsync(x => mapFileUploadEntities.Any(m => m.MapName == x.MapName)).ConfigureAwait(false);
               //push notification
            }
            else if(aDFPipeLineStatus.Status == "Failed")
            {
                
                MapUpload mapUpload = await MapUploadRepository.GetFirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.MapId == 9);
                var mapUploadData = await this.MapUploadRepository.GetAsync(x => mapFileUploadEntities.Any(m => m.MapName == x.MapName)).ConfigureAwait(false);
                //push notification
            }
        }
```

In the above code when I call `await this.MapUploadRepository.GetAsync(x => mapFileUploadEntities.Any(m => m.MapName == x.MapName)).ConfigureAwait(false);` it throws

> Cannot access a disposed object.  A common cause of this error is
> disposing a context that was resolved from dependency  injection and
> then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your
> application.  This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the
> context, or wrapping the context in a using statement.  If you are
> using dependency injection, you should let the dependency  injection
> container take care of disposing context instances.\r\nObject name:
> 'MyContext'."

Is the Task.Delay making this problem? I have below registration in my startup.cs

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
           options.UseSqlServer(this.Configuration["AzureSQLConnectionString"]));

services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
```

Can someone help me to understand what I am doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please, provide full code of the class. It seems like the issue is not in `UploadMapFile` method

Comment: Thanks Alexander. I added but Dbcontext will disposes after the await Task.Delay(15000);?

Comment: Hi Alexander I tried something like this using (var serviceScope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
                {
                    var db = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<SiteEnrichmentContext>();
                    var blogs = db.MapUpload.Where(x => x.MapName == "test").FirstOrDefault();} It worked for me

Comment: But this dint work  MapUpload mapUpload = await MapUploadRepository.GetFirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.MapId == 9); that means my Unitofwork and repository still holding disposed context

Answer (score 0):

Make sure **the caller** of your UploadMapFile() method (as well as **ALL** the higher methods in this call stack) **is awaiting the retuned Task**.
If instead somewhere in the call stack you return void instead of Task, the call will be ended and DbContext will be disposed.

This problem is discussed in detail here:
[Cannot access a disposed object in ASP.NET Core when injecting DbContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38704025/cannot-access-a-disposed-object-in-asp-net-core-when-injecting-dbcontext)