# Getting "'Cannot access a disposed object" error when trying to update database on startup using EF Core in Web API Core

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

We have a Web API Core application that use the EF Core with the SQL Server in a backend. I am trying to update one of the database tables whenever the Web API service starts (in a Startup.cs Configure method)

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, SomeDBContext dataContext, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{ 
    .......................
    // Automatically perform database migration
    dataContext.Database.Migrate();

    PopulateSomeTable(dataContext);
}

private async void PopulateSomeTable(SomeDBContext context)
{
    var someTables = context.SomeTables;
    if (someTables != null && (await someTables .CountAsync()) == 0)
    {
         someTables .Add(new Entities.SomeTable
         {
             someProperty1= 20,
             someProperty2 = "Something",
             someProperty3 = DateTimeOffset.Now,
         });
         await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

However, when I try to access the context I get this error

> Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is
> disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and
> then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your
> application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the
> context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are
> using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection
> container take care of disposing context

How can I fix it?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

remove all your code from startup, it is not the best place to make db migration, and add only this code

```
 public static void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, MyDbContext context)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();
         }
    }
```

add this code to ConfigureServices of startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
           options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
              new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());

services.AddDbContext<SomeDBContext (options => 
options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("CategoryDbConnection")));
```

to populate data  add code like this OnModelCreating of SomeDBContext

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SomeTable>().HasData(
    new SomeTable{ ....
                 });
```

to migrate classes to database tables  follow this link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=vs

Comment: Thank you! Is there a quick way to reference db context?

Comment: How can I call PopulateSomeTable? How can I create/reference the db context variable?

Comment: Thank you @Serge, the code compiles but nothing saves in the DB, the table stays empty :-( Is there some additional trick/setting I need to apply?

Comment: Pls post update, i want to see your hasdata, the real one. It can be an error there

Comment: I just found out that it works ONLY if I run add-migration AND update-database. Is there a way for this to work WITHOUT having to run the shell commands? Thank you once again for your kind help

Comment: @James I updated my also. Also in the end of article of my answer link you can find how to include migration in  program main method if you are not happy with this.

Comment: Serge, are you referring to Managig Migrations article or to Design time DB context creation article?

Comment: @James yes, this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=vs

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `private async void PopulateSomeTable(SomeDBContext context)` to `private async Task PopulateSomeTable(SomeDBContext context)`. Replace `async void` to `async task`. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38704025/cannot-access-a-disposed-object-in-asp-net-core-when-injecting-dbcontext?rq=1) for more info.